# In a rail application i want to authorize admin to create a new record in particular module.not any user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Requirement:
I have  a deal module in my rail application. when the user click on create new deal link  it will check chat whether the user is admin or not.if the user is admin i want to allow 
it to create a new deal otherwise it will display a flash message that you are not allowed and redirect the user to signin page to login as admin.if the user sign in as admin i want to redirect it to  a page from where it previously comes.

Answer (score 1):

[Devise and cancan](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) should help

Comment: Can you Please help me in generating pdf file in rail 3.0